# C++ to C# port question: How would I deal with a method that has a double* as a parameter?

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, porting

I'm porting a C++ library to C# and I've encountered some methods that have double* pointers as parameters. What's the best way to deal with this? Perhaps modify the calling code so that it's not passing pointers? I WOULD just wrap the code in an "unsafe" block and set the compiler's /unsafe flag, but I can't do that inside of the method signature.

Comment: What is the code doing with the double*?  Are they being used as arrays?  Are they being used to return values?

Comment: Do you mean pointer to a double or 'type ** name' as a pointer to an array of type?

Comment: You should post some of the C++, as it depends on how the  double* is being used.  Most probably the double is being passed by reference to allow its value to be changed, in which case you can use ref/out - but there are other possibilities.

Comment: No, it is not being passed by reference. There are no ampersands on the params.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe uusing `ref` (or `out`) on parameters may be good enough, or if you need to handle an array of those use a `double[]`.

Maybe post the method definition so that it gets clearer what you really need.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you wish to use managed safe code

Depends on how the pointer is used. If it's used as an array inside your method then you'll need to pass an array to the method and therefor need to change the signature.

if it's used as a double and (re)assigned it again depends. Does the method have return type? if so using ref double might be the way to go. if the method doesn't have a return type return the value being assigned and let the caller passing to a local instead of passing by ref.

if the double* is used as a double and never assign simply pass as double.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it translates to ref double or out double or double[]. Which it should be depends on the semantics of the code. C++ double* can actually mean a number of things.

It's highly unlikely that unsafe code is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could mark the function as `unsafe` and compile with the **/unsafe** flag:

```
private static unsafe void MyFunction(double *d)
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8.aspx

Comment: I did not downvote, but I have a feeling it's from advocating the use of `unsafe` without a clear reason that it's needed; it's very likely that the OP's code can be easily written with managed idioms.

Comment: That is very true, and I completely agree that it can be done other ways. However, the OP said he *would* wrap it in an unsafe block, but couldn't include the method signature. This answer says that you can use the unsafe keyword to include the parameters in the unsafe declaration.

Comment: True enough, but given that the OP asked "What's the best way to deal with this", I think that's where most people are coming from; not just that it *can* be done other ways, but it almost certainly *should* be done another way.

Comment: While Evan's answer may not be the BEST solution from a memory safety perspective, I cetrtainly learned something new: being able to mark a method as unsafe. I will accept an answer once I've had a chance to try out a couple solutions. Thanks for the great input guys!!!

Answer (score 0):

Where you are passing pointers, you are simply changing the default *pass-by-value* mechanism to *pass-by-reference*, in which case, use the `ref` keyword:

```
public void SomeMethod(ref double val) { }
```

In which you need to ensure you specifiy `ref` when call it too:

```
SomeMethod(ref 12.0);
```

Comment: This is assuming he's not passing an array.

Comment: Unnecessary downvote? If there is an issue with this answer, please write a comment.

Answer (score 0):

What you do will depend on how the pointer is being used. If the pointer is there so that the calling code can pass an array of `double`s, then have the method accept a `double[]`. If the pointer is there so that the called code can modify the value of a `double` variable from the caller, then you have two choices:

- Modify the semantics of the call in such a way that the `double` is a return value (this would be the way I'd suggest)
- Declare the parameter as `ref` or `out` (depending on whether or not you want to guarantee that the called function will assign a value.

Don't just throw `unsafe` blocks around code so that you can continue to use pointers; `unsafe` should be used *very* sparingly (ideally not at all).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the function uses the pointer.  You don't really give enough info to give a solid answer, but I'll give it a shot anyway.

**Normal C# code**

If the code in the method is de-referencing the pointer and assigning a value, without doing any pointer arithmetic, then simply make the parameter an `out` parameter.

If the previous paragraph is true, and you don't already have a return value, simply modify the signature of the method to return a `double`.

If the code is not doing pointer arithmetic, but *uses* the value that already exists at the pointed location, as well as assigning it, then make the parameter a `ref` parameter.

If the code does no pointer arithmetic, uses the value, but doesn't assign it, then you should probably change it from a pointer to a plain `double`, and not make it `ref` or `out`.

If the implementation of the function is doing pointer arithmetic, then you'll need to build and pass some sort of indexable collection, such as one that implements `IList` or an array.

**Alternatives to normal C# code**

You could always opt to mark your code `unsafe`, too, and use pointers.  That will probably be a lot more work than simple logical translations, but is more likely to maintain a similar performance profile.

You could also opt to use C++/CLI instead of C#.  It is also a .Net langauge, and might be simpler (depending on your app) to integrate directly with the existing C++ code.

Comment: Thanks Merlyn. Great in-depth answer. After going back to the C++ library I'm porting, I see that the static class that contains the method in question doesn't even get used anywhere except in some sample code. The method is used for calculating Lagrange points in astronimcal calculations.